# When to use holes instead of side terminals to wire an outlet

Tags: electrical, gfci, outlets

This question comes from Shirlock's comment on [this GFCI wiring question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7974/proper-wiring-for-gfci-given-switched-circuit/7975#7975).

When and why should you use the holes on the back of an outlet rather than the side terminals?  I always assumed the holes on the back were only for lazy electricians and people that wanted to make my life miserable, especially when there isn't much slack wire and you want to replace an outlet.  Are there other reasons, and does the NEC have any requirements on one vs the other?

Comment: Holes in the back were news to me...my sore hands would love an answer.

Comment: @six: BYW, a good pair of diagonal cutters (dikes) makes easy work of making curls in 12 and 14 AWG solid wire.  Use the curve of the back or the blades to make a nice "C" by grabbing the end of the bare wire in the cutter blade, squeeze gently and roll the wire around the back of the jaws ( blades).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are no NEC guides, UL and CSA rules on or approves devices.  The reason I commented on using back wiring on GFI's, is that if you look carefully inside the holes, you will see a barbed plate that compresses on the wire when the side screw is tightened. You will also notice because the device itself is very wide, there is little barrier space around the screws. Most manufacturers recommend using the strip gage and back wiring holes.  Just be sure to tip the device so the grab plates open before inserting the wires. Every electrician I know uses the back connections on GFI's and side wires regular receptacles.  Also notice that there are holes for 4 pairs of wires, two pairs for line side and two pairs for load side. Again, this saves room in the box so fewer wirenuts and splices need to be used.

Comment: Interesting, so it's just space saving and the fact that the screws clamp in the wire (rather than friction) and not a safety concern with water leakage.  Thanks Shirlock, I'm still learning something new everyday.

Comment: "Every electrician I know, uses the back connections on GFI's and side wires regular receptacles." Although this may be true, every house I have torn into in order to replace receptacles has used the back holes for everything.

Comment: @kellenjb:   that is because they are just trying to cut time.  Good electricians side wire regular recpts

Comment: And I've lived in houses where those back push-in connections have relaxed, and have removed the charred plastic that results. As an end socket maybe, but as the first socket in a daisy chain? Potential future fire hazard. Most sockets nowdays have side clamp (straight wire) plates underneath the screw. Use those, not the push-ins.

Comment: You can get regular outlets and switches with the same style of connection as GFCIs. You can also get GFCIs that only have a screw connection.

Comment: Yes, pulling a wire out of the back of regular outlets without damaging it is not easy. Here's a time-saving tip if you are replacing a bad outlet: get a large pair of channel-lock or similar, and crush the outlet like a walnut. Then it's easy to remove the little brass traps from the wires. Even after sweeping up the mess, it's still a lot faster and easier than trying to pull them out, and you won't damage the ends and then need to cut them shorter.

Comment: I would say good electricians use spec grade outlets that are back and side type with the clamps and never use back stabs. I toss those home grade under a dollar receptacles in the trash.

Answer (score 28):

Shirlock has a great answer; I just wanted to point out something. There are two major different designs for back-wiring, "push-in" and "side-clamp".

Push-in wiring, sometimes branded "QuickWire", uses holes in the plastic casing, underneath which are sharp spring-loaded cleats that catch and hold the wire when you put it in. To remove them, you take a jeweler's screwdriver or a small pick or probe and push into a square tab nearby, which pushes the cleat away allowing you to withdraw the wire. Personally, I hate these things with a passion and prefer to side-wire. They only work with one gauge of wire (either 12 or 14AWG depending on the type of switch or outlet; do YOU know which one was used in every single J-box in your home?), and getting the wire back out without destroying the wire or the switch is a crap shoot. The push-release mechanism is as likely to crumple and lock the wire in as to release it, IME.

Side-clamp wiring, sometimes branded "EZ-Wire", uses a plate between the side-wiring screw and the switch body. You loosen the screw, separate the plate from the switch body (easiest to let gravity do the work; turn it plate-down and shake), insert the wire stripped to the proper length, then tighten down the side screw. It works a lot like side-wiring, except you don't have to curl the wire around the screw. They're pretty easy to use and are VERY secure, and so I like these a lot better than the push-in wiring setups. The only possible problem is, with a lot of exposed metal on the side of the switch body, you have to be certain you don't short out the switch to the bare metal ground wire, or the next switch or outlet over (very easy with the wider 20A switches and GFCI outlets). I did that a few times while repairing the electrical in my new home; the switch or plug worked fine hanging loose, but when I closed it up it stopped working. The fail-safe is to give the switch body a wrap of electrical tape, giving it an insulating layer between the switch and anything else in the box (and the box itself; most are plastic but I found a couple conductive switch/outlet J-boxes in my home).

Comment: Good explanation of exactly what I was referring to.  I always wrap devices with 33+ electrical tape in mult-device or metal boxes. If I ever have to release a friction back wired device, I replace it or only side wire it, never try to reuse the back push-in hole connector.  +vote

Comment: Using electrical tape to protect against a short like that is asking for trouble - if there is any physical contact, you won't know it when you close the box. It will eventually wear (movement through plug insertion/removal, shifting, thermal expansion/contraction, piercing from pressure - and tape is a soft material), then you'll have arcing in your box - a good recipe for a fire. Better off to know you have an issue, and fix it with physical separation, than patch it.

Comment: ... I might agree, but with these wider 20A or GCFI node bodies that are the case in point, there's usually very little wiggle room and so physical separation isn't possible. I've never closed up a box with any two switches or plugs visibly touching, but I don't think it's a bad idea to give the switch a wrap of tape.

Comment: I don't see any way tape could do harm, if things are installed properly to begin with -- and it might help if something comes loose. Immediate failure is better than late failure, but no failure beats both.

Comment: Most side-clamp devices allow for two wires to be inserted under each plate.  I've found it only works well if the two wires are the same gage, construction (solid/stranded) and manufacturer.  Any slight difference between them, and one of them ends up not being held as well as the other and works its way loose.

Answer (score 1):

There is never a good time to use push in wiring of the receptacle. Does not hold tight especially after the outlet has seen a little bit of use. Wires loosen get hot and burn out and if you don't find in time it will burn your house down!

Comment: I'm not sure this answer, as it's written, adds much to the other answers. Maybe you can expand a bit.  Recall personal experiences, site studies, etc.?

Comment: A friend of mine handles consumer complaints against insurance companies (in the U.S.) and based on the complaints he's handled, he will flat out say "never" use back stabs because of the risk of fire.

Comment: TL;DR: Never, ever.

Answer (score 0):

I have had multiple experiences that have had the push-in lose their connection, and the solution was to change it to use the side screws.  For that reason I recommend always using the screws.

Comment: If you look at the warnings on those things carefully, they specifically tell you not to reuse the QuickWire clamps. Once you've inserted and released a wire once, you're side-wiring; that's a major reason they're pretty much gone in new switches.