# How to finish the wiring of a shared GFCI receptacle

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

My neighbor who is an electrician helped me start an electrical project in my garage but has been MIA for 3 weeks and I'm not sure how to finish the wiring of the receptacles.  He didn't seem to start it in a very straighforward way.  In the garage i now have (4) new receptacles and (3) new breakers.  The breakers are labeled "drill press", "vac", and "saw".  I asked for the vac to be on it's own 20amp breaker and the saw and drill press could share a breaker as they're never on at the same time but the vac is on at the same time as everything else.  (2) of the breakers share a single romex coming out with (2) hots, (1) neutral, and (1) ground.  The 3rd breaker has it's own set of (1) ea hot/neutral, ground.  They all meet in a junction box.  From that junction box they go to another junction box where they split directions.  In one direction toward the drill press i'm sending 1 ea hot, neutral and ground.  To the other set of three receptacles i'm sending (2) hots, (1) neutral, and (1) ground. These are tied to the red/black hots from the shared romex. They then meet in a box that is a gfci receptacle for the saw.  in the gfci box i've wired one of the hots and the only neutral into the gfci.  on the load side of the gfci saw receptacle i'm sending a hot to the other saw receptacle.  i have a pigtail coming out of the neutral/load side of the gfci that is tying together the neutrals from both the vac receptacle which has it's own hot and the other saw receptacle.

Did i screw this up?  It doesn't seem right that the vac and saw can share a neutral if they're running at the same time.  i also asked for everything to be on gfci but not sure this is the case either.  let me know if pictures would help.
Thank you for any advice you can offer.

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/8900/2196) should help you. From your description, you're sharing a neutral on a GFCI with a hot that's not on the GFCI, which will always trip the GFCI by design.

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/9332/33) is also helpful, and has pictures!

Comment: Please make sure that the 20 amp circuit has 12 gauge wire (the others could as well, but the 12 requires it).